# JPA | Loop through list of ids AND UPDATE C

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, jpa, postgis

I am facing issue with JPA Query. Database is Postgres.

I want to update a column value by passing some count value which will update multiple rows by 1.

Eg:

Table A

Column : Id, rank , name

For sql query input is

startRank : 10

ids : [2,3,5]

Output:

It should update rank 10 at row with id 2 , 11 at row with id 3 and 12 at row with id 5.

Please suggest is it achieve via Java in JPA or direct in sql and how?

P.S. : Previously I used prepared statement and build a query in loop and dispatch it for execute. Now in JPA I dont know the way.

Comment: add your current code example.. will be  more clear

Comment: Current code example : 


Table Story having fields 
Id , Name , Rank 
Now i have list of ids which we need to update (say 3,7,9) and rank : 16
So i want to frame a query in JPA which iterate over ids 3 7 and 9 and set the rank value 16 ,17 and 18. Also I have to change the name to prefix-16, prefix-17 , prefix-18  
So final output will be ID "3" Name "Prefix-16" Rank "16" , ID "7" Name "Prefix-17" Rank "17" , ID "9" Name "Prefix-18" Rank "18"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of my question :

We need to put the annotation '@Transactional'in service class and run the loop from service to update method present in repository, this will create entity objects in java and at end of service method it pushes all the created entities in database.

Code Snippet :

```
     @Transactional
            void method(x){
//Given: Array id[] and rank
            for ( int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
                            rank= rank+1
                            repository.update(id[i],rank);
                        }
            }
```

Repository method :

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true) 
        @Query(value =   "UPDATE stories "
                        + "SET rank = :rank, "
                        + "WHERE id = :storyId ;" ,nativeQuery = true) 
    void update(@Param("storyId") Integer storyId, @Param("rank") int rank);
}
```